# How can I change QTableWidgetItem notation to standardNotation

Tags: qt, qt4, qtablewidget, qt4.8, qtablewidgetitem

I have QTableWidget with 3 columns. I multiply numbers in first and second column and write result in third column. Numbers are double. The problem is: result is in scientific notation like "1.4e+3". How can I change notation to standard notation?
I use Qt 4.8 and Ubuntu 12.10.

I populate first two columns:

```
QTableWidgetItem *itm0=new QTableWidgetItem("12345.6781");
ui->tableWidget->setItem(0,0,itm0);
QTableWidgetItem *itm1=new QTableWidgetItem("223.132");
ui->tableWidget->setItem(0,1,itm1);
```

I multiply numbers and write result

```
double num0=ui->tableWidget->item(0,0)->text().toDouble();
double num1=ui->tableWidget->item(0,1)->text().toDouble();
double result=num0*num1;

QTableWidgetItem *itm2=new QTableWidgetItem(QString::number(result));
ui->tableWidget->setItem(0,2,itm2);
```

result is 2.75472e+06,
but actually result is 2754715,8458092

Comment: Show some code, specifically the code which does the calculation and puts the result into the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are using `QString::number` function . You can use the second argument of this function to specify how the conversion from double to QString will be done. Here are the outputs :

```
double num = 1234.4565;
qDebug()<< QString::number(num);//"1234.46" 
qDebug()<< QString::number(num, 'e');//"1.234457e+03" 
qDebug()<< QString::number(num, 'f');//"1234.456500"
```

**Use**
**'e'** format as [-]9.9e[+|-]999
**'E'** format as [-]9.9E[+|-]999
**'f'** format as [-]9.9
**'g'** use e or f format, whichever is the most concise
**'G'** use E or f format, whichever is the most concise
Assistant is my best friend ;)